# MUI transition component forward ref typescript typing issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Trying to use the transitions components provided by MUI such as `Grow, Fade, etc` and am keep getting type errors regarding the `ref` prop.

```
const MyTransition = forwardRef<object, object>(
  function transition(props, ref) {
    return (
      <div {...props} ref={ref ? ref : null}> <--- Getting error here
        <Grid item={true} xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Inputs ... />
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  });

...
...

<Grow>
  <MyTransition />
</Grow>
```

I keep getting an error for the `ref` prop I am providing to `div`. Also changed this to `Fragment` and other components but keep getting errors related to types.

With the div I get:

> Type '((instance: object | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<object | null> | null' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef | undefined'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject<object | null>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef | undefined'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject<object | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject'.
> Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
> Type 'object | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLDivElement': align, addEventListener, removeEventListener, accessKey, and 291 more.

The MUI docs [link](https://mui.com/material-ui/transitions/#child-requirement)